# Connecting through pywinrm and execute a PowerShell script that triggers a video

Tags: python, powershell, winrm

I need to connect to Windows from Linux machine and execute a PowerShell script. The PowerShell script will invoke a video file (mp4 file).

What I have done till now:

1. Installed open ssh in windows, installed pywinrm in Linux
2. Established connection and ran few commands (Ipconfig, dir etc)

But I'm unable to invoke a video file

Code from Linux:

```
# Create a Pywinrm connection.

import winrm
sess = winrm.Session('192.168.25.82', auth=('administrator', 'w$xV&tf*zr'))
#result = sess.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
#print(result.status_code)
#print(result.std_out)
#res1 = sess.run_ps('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\play_video.ps1')
res1 = sess.run_ps('.\play_video.ps1')
print(res1.std_out)
```

If I try IPconfig/Dir it runs perfectly fine. If I want to invoke a wmplayer file  it is not working

PS1 file  (I'm new to power shell - This ps1 file works fine in Windows machine. But does not work when triggered through winrm)

```
$wmp = New-Object -ComObject WMPlayer.OCX
$wmp.openPlayer("C:\Movies\ARP_5_30_19_6_2018.mp4")
$wmp.controls.play()
$wmp.controls.pause()
```

I tried Python, bat files even. Unable to invoke a video remotely. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.